# std::async with std::future_status::timeout, times out every alternate time on iOS only

Tags: ios, c++11, clang, c++14, stdasync

I am using an `std::async` in the `C++` part of my app to do a `heavy transaction` which has chances of taking a very long time in case of something wrong with the network. So I use an `std::async` combined with `std::future` waiting for a time out set which saves me from getting hung up when the transaction takes very very long. It gets called every time the user clicks a certain button on `UI`.

This `C++` code of mine gets used on 4 different platforms, namely `iOS, Android, OSX & Windows`. Following is way I use `std::async` to do this heavy operation.

```
//Do the operation in async
std::future<size_t> my_future_result(std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() {
  size_t result = someHeavyFunctionCall();
  return result;
}));

//try to get the status of the operation after a time_out
std::future_status my_future_status = my_future_result.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(some_time_out));
if (my_future_status == std::future_status::timeout) {
  std::cout << "it times out every alternate time on ios only" << std::endl;
}
else if (my_future_status == std::future_status::ready) {
  if (my_future_result.get() > 0)
      //we are all fine
}
```

Above `std::async & std::future_status` technique works fine on all platforms. Its only on `iOS`, I get a problem where the `future` times out every alternate time the user clicks the button.

**Is there something I should correct upon the way I am using `std::async & std::future_status` ? What might be wrong ?** I have tried to search this a lot. I don't get anything other that the information that `std::async` is not ready for all platforms. Am I hitting a problem that `std::async` has on `iOS` ?

I am new to this kind of `async+futures` based `C++` programming. Do, let me know if I am doing an obvious mistake here

Comment: Could it just be noise, or an unluckily chosen timeout? Try doubling (or halving) the timeout, and see if it never (or always) times out.

Comment: @melak47 I tried increasing the timeout. cud not get it to work on ios. it only & only happens on ios